# How to keep certain structure in various text files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-re

I have some .WOC files like(let's say File1):

```
Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?
    
144 cm/35 Kg/5 YearsOld
    
    
    
    
    
    
45,34,22,26,0
78,74,82,11,0
```

and other ones like (File 2):

```
Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?
    
126cm/45 Kg/13 YearsOld.
    

MON/age/sex/hei/weight/tsle/twak/dev/mans/g/sc/sl/br/n
126/13.00/0/158.0/45.2/21.30/7.00/CC:/S/E YearsOld.
    
45,34,22,26,0
78,74,82,11,0
```

and another type like (File 3):

```
Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?
    
144 cm/35 Kg/5 YearsOld

S:22W:7;A:r;E:j; RRv:0/0; RRn:0/0

-

nFehl= 12

-

-   
    
    
129,96,79,10,52
134,99,77,9,52
```

Using the code below, I am able to convert File 1 to dataframe and my expected output dataframe looks like:

```
A, B, C, D, E, City, Height, Weight, Age
45,34,22,26,0,NewYork, 144,    35,   5
78,74,82,11,0,NewYork, 144,    35,   5
```

The code is:

```
with open('File 1.woc', 'r') as f:
    heading_rows = [next(f) for _ in range(5)]

city = re.findall(pattern = ' \w+ ', string = heading_rows[0])[0].strip()

numbers_list = [re.findall(pattern='\d+', string=row) for row in heading_rows if 'cm' and 'kg' in row.lower()][0]

height, weight, age = [int(numbers_lst[i]) for i in range(3)]
    
df = pd.read_csv('File 1.woc', sep='\s+|;|,', skiprows=2,comment='cm', index_col=None, names=list('ABCDE'))
    
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

How can I edit all text files so that all look like File 1? I do not mind if characters in between are deleted.

Comment: would it matter if the blank lines in every file (including file1) were removed ?

Comment: first two lines should stay, because I will use them in a dataframe

Comment: yes - but was wondering if the `blank lines` between them could be removed?

Comment: exactly, blank lines can be removed since they do not matter

Comment: @ScottC it is a mistake. There should be 5 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will extract the relevant info from each file in question:

- Provide the `number_of_files` - each of which are named `File x.woc`

**To find the lines to keep:**

1. Find the lines starting with "Person"
2. Find the lines that contain the word "cm"
3. Find the lines that have 5 numbers separated by a comma (using regex)

**Here is the code**

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+,?){5}')

number_of_files = 3

for i in range(number_of_files):
    
    # Open file and extract lines of interest
    filename = f"File {i+1}.woc"
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    lines_to_keep = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Person:') or 'cm' in line or pattern.search(line):
            lines_to_keep.append(line)
        
    # Create a new file in the desired format
    newfilename = f"new_File {i+1}.woc"
    with open(newfilename, 'w') as fp:
        for line in lines_to_keep:
            fp.write(line)
```

**new_File 1.woc:**

```
Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?
144 cm/35 Kg/5 YearsOld
45,34,22,26,0
78,74,82,11,0
```

**new_File 2.woc:**

```
Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?
126cm/45 Kg/13 YearsOld
45,34,22,26,0
78,74,82,11,0
```

**new_File 3.woc:**

```
Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?
144 cm/35 Kg/5 YearsOld
129,96,79,10,52
134,99,77,9,52
```

Comment: it works thanks! How should I twist the code if I have multiple similar charachter? I realized there is additional YearsOld line with weird characters. I just edited the question for that case in File 2.

Comment: you could search for `Kg` or `cm` instead ?? Providing they are not within other lines

Comment: I was trying to implement double or cases. Thanks!